# Understanding bandwidth smoothing in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

realdata = https://www.dropbox.com/s/pc5tp2lfhafgaiy/realdata.txt

simulation = https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ep95808xg7bon3/simulation.txt

A density plot of this data using bandwidth=1.5 gives me the following plot:

```
prealdata = scan("realdata.txt")
simulation = scan("simulation.txt")
plot(density(log10(realdata), bw=1.5))
lines(density(log10(simulation), bw=1.5), lty=2)
```

[image]

But using ggplot2 to plot the same data, bandwidth argument (adjust) seems to be working differently. Why?

```
vec1 = data.frame(x=log10(realdata))
vec2 = data.frame(x=log10(simulation))
require(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
geom_density(aes(x=x, linetype="real data"), data=vec1, adjust=1.5) +
geom_density(aes(x=x, linetype="simulation"), data=vec2, adjust=1.5) +
scale_linetype_manual(name="data", values=c("real data"="solid", "simulation"="dashed"))
```

[image]

**Suggestions on how to better smooth this data are also very welcome!**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`adjust=` is not the same as `bw=`. When you plot

```
plot(density(log10(realdata), bw=1.5))
lines(density(log10(simulation), bw=1.5), lty=2)
```

you get the same thing as `ggplot`

[image]

For whatever reason, `ggplot` does not allow you to specify a `bw=` parameter. By default, `density` uses `bw.nrd0()` so while you changed this for the plot using base graphics, you cannot change this value using `ggplot`. But what get's used is `adjust*bw`. So since we know how to calculate the default `bw`, we can recalculate `adjust=` to give use the same value.

```
#helper function
bw<-function(b, x) { b/bw.nrd0(x) }

require(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
geom_density(aes(x=x, linetype="real data"), data=vec1, adjust=bw(1.5, vec1$x)) +
geom_density(aes(x=x, linetype="simulation"), data=vec2, adjust=bw(1.5, vec2$x)) +
scale_linetype_manual(name="data", 
    values=c("real data"="solid", "simulation"="dashed"))
```

And that results in

[image]

which is the same as the base graphics plot.

Comment: Just an update, `bw` is now in the list of parameters for `geom_density`.